# Linking error when I integrate c++ library in ios

Tags: c++, ios, native, wrapper

[image]

This is my file tree in the project

And the error is appeared like below

```
Ld /Users/chanwoo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/face-recog-test9-fauksbwwzfttmcdxrlvcyghtcloj/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/face-recog-test9.app/face-recog-test9 normal arm64 (in target 'face-recog-test9' from project 'face-recog-test9')
    cd /Users/chanwoo/Documents/Repositories/resonance/ios_projects/face-recog-test9
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -target arm64-apple-ios13.4 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.4.sdk -L/Users/chanwoo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/face-recog-test9-fauksbwwzfttmcdxrlvcyghtcloj/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos -L/Users/chanwoo/Documents/Repositories/resonance/ios_projects/face-recog-test9/lib/ -F/Users/chanwoo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/face-recog-test9-fauksbwwzfttmcdxrlvcyghtcloj/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos -filelist /Users/chanwoo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/face-recog-test9-fauksbwwzfttmcdxrlvcyghtcloj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/face-recog-test9.build/Release-iphoneos/face-recog-test9.build/Objects-normal/arm64/face-recog-test9.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/chanwoo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/face-recog-test9-fauksbwwzfttmcdxrlvcyghtcloj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/face-recog-test9.build/Release-iphoneos/face-recog-test9.build/Objects-normal/arm64/face-recog-test9_lto.o -fembed-bitcode-marker -stdlib=libc++ -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos -L/usr/lib/swift -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/chanwoo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/face-recog-test9-fauksbwwzfttmcdxrlvcyghtcloj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/face-recog-test9.build/Release-iphoneos/face-recog-test9.build/Objects-normal/arm64/face_recog_test9.swiftmodule -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/chanwoo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/face-recog-test9-fauksbwwzfttmcdxrlvcyghtcloj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/face-recog-test9.build/Release-iphoneos/face-recog-test9.build/Objects-normal/arm64/face-recog-test9_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/chanwoo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/face-recog-test9-fauksbwwzfttmcdxrlvcyghtcloj/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/face-recog-test9.app/face-recog-test9

Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "dlib::scrollable_region::set_total_rect_size(unsigned long, unsigned long)", referenced from:
      void dlib::image_display::set_image<dlib::array2d<unsigned char, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > >(dlib::array2d<unsigned char, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > const&) in Test.o
      void dlib::image_display::set_image<dlib::matrix_op<dlib::op_heatmap<dlib::array2d<unsigned char, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > > > >(dlib::matrix_op<dlib::op_heatmap<dlib::array2d<unsigned char, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > > > const&) in Test.o
      void dlib::image_display::set_image<dlib::matrix_op<dlib::op_jet<dlib::array2d<unsigned char, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > > > >(dlib::matrix_op<dlib::op_jet<dlib::array2d<unsigned char, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > > > const&) in Test.o
      void dlib::image_display::set_image<dlib::array2d<dlib::rgb_pixel, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > >(dlib::array2d<dlib::rgb_pixel, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > const&) in Test.o
  "dlib::base_window::close_window()", referenced from:
      dlib::drawable_window::~drawable_window() in Test.o
  "dlib::image_display::get_image_display_rect() const", referenced from:
      void dlib::image_window::set_image<dlib::array2d<unsigned char, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > >(dlib::array2d<unsigned char, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > const&) in Test.o
      void dlib::image_window::set_image<dlib::matrix_op<dlib::op_heatmap<dlib::array2d<unsigned char, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > > > >(dlib::matrix_op<dlib::op_heatmap<dlib::array2d<unsigned char, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > > > const&) in Test.o
      void dlib::image_window::set_image<dlib::matrix_op<dlib::op_jet<dlib::array2d<unsigned char, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > > > >(dlib::matrix_op<dlib::op_jet<dlib::array2d<unsigned char, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > > > const&) in Test.o
      void dlib::image_window::set_image<dlib::array2d<dlib::rgb_pixel, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > >(dlib::array2d<dlib::rgb_pixel, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > const&) in Test.o
  "dlib::base_window::invalidate_rectangle(dlib::rectangle const&)", referenced from:
      dlib::image_display::disable_overlay_editing() in Test.o
      void dlib::image_display::set_image<dlib::array2d<unsigned char, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > >(dlib::array2d<unsigned char, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > const&) in Test.o
      void dlib::image_display::set_image<dlib::matrix_op<dlib::op_heatmap<dlib::array2d<unsigned char, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > > > >(dlib::matrix_op<dlib::op_heatmap<dlib::array2d<unsigned char, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > > > const&) in Test.o
      void dlib::image_display::set_image<dlib::matrix_op<dlib::op_jet<dlib::array2d<unsigned char, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > > > >(dlib::matrix_op<dlib::op_jet<dlib::array2d<unsigned char, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > > > const&) in Test.o
      void dlib::image_display::set_image<dlib::array2d<dlib::rgb_pixel, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > >(dlib::array2d<dlib::rgb_pixel, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > const&) in Test.o
  "dlib::base_window::base_window(bool, bool)", referenced from:
      dlib::drawable_window::drawable_window(bool, bool) in Test.o
  "dlib::base_window::~base_window()", referenced from:
      dlib::drawable_window::drawable_window(bool, bool) in Test.o
      dlib::drawable_window::~drawable_window() in Test.o
  "dlib::base_window::set_size(int, int)", referenced from:
      void dlib::image_window::set_image<dlib::array2d<unsigned char, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > >(dlib::array2d<unsigned char, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > const&) in Test.o
      void dlib::image_window::set_image<dlib::matrix_op<dlib::op_heatmap<dlib::array2d<unsigned char, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > > > >(dlib::matrix_op<dlib::op_heatmap<dlib::array2d<unsigned char, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > > > const&) in Test.o
      void dlib::image_window::set_image<dlib::matrix_op<dlib::op_jet<dlib::array2d<unsigned char, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > > > >(dlib::matrix_op<dlib::op_jet<dlib::array2d<unsigned char, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > > > const&) in Test.o
      void dlib::image_window::set_image<dlib::array2d<dlib::rgb_pixel, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > >(dlib::array2d<dlib::rgb_pixel, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > const&) in Test.o
  "vtable for dlib::image_window", referenced from:
      dlib::image_window::image_window<dlib::array2d<unsigned char, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > >(dlib::array2d<unsigned char, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in Test.o
      dlib::image_window::image_window<dlib::matrix_op<dlib::op_heatmap<dlib::array2d<unsigned char, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > > > >(dlib::matrix_op<dlib::op_heatmap<dlib::array2d<unsigned char, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > > > const&) in Test.o
      dlib::image_window::image_window<dlib::matrix_op<dlib::op_jet<dlib::array2d<unsigned char, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > > > >(dlib::matrix_op<dlib::op_jet<dlib::array2d<unsigned char, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > > > const&) in Test.o
      dlib::image_window::image_window<dlib::array2d<dlib::rgb_pixel, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > >(dlib::array2d<dlib::rgb_pixel, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in Test.o
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
  "dlib::base_window::set_title(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&)", referenced from:
      dlib::image_window::image_window<dlib::array2d<unsigned char, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > >(dlib::array2d<unsigned char, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in Test.o
      dlib::image_window::image_window<dlib::array2d<dlib::rgb_pixel, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > >(dlib::array2d<dlib::rgb_pixel, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in Test.o
  "dlib::entropy_decoder_kernel_2::decode(unsigned int, unsigned int)", referenced from:
      dlib::entropy_decoder_model_kernel_5<256ul, dlib::entropy_decoder_kernel_2, 200000ul, 4ul>::decode(unsigned long&) in Test.o
      dlib::entropy_decoder_model_kernel_4<256ul, dlib::entropy_decoder_kernel_2, 200000ul, 4ul>::decode(unsigned long&) in Test.o
  "dlib::entropy_decoder_kernel_2::get_target(unsigned int)", referenced from:
      dlib::entropy_decoder_model_kernel_5<256ul, dlib::entropy_decoder_kernel_2, 200000ul, 4ul>::decode(unsigned long&) in Test.o
      dlib::entropy_decoder_model_kernel_4<256ul, dlib::entropy_decoder_kernel_2, 200000ul, 4ul>::decode(unsigned long&) in Test.o
  "vtable for dlib::drawable_window", referenced from:
      dlib::drawable_window::drawable_window(bool, bool) in Test.o
      dlib::drawable_window::~drawable_window() in Test.o
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
  "dlib::entropy_decoder_kernel_2::entropy_decoder_kernel_2()", referenced from:
      void dlib::load_dng<dlib::array2d<dlib::rgb_pixel, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > >(dlib::array2d<dlib::rgb_pixel, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> >&, std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) in Test.o
  "dlib::base_window::wait_until_closed() const", referenced from:
      Test::test(int, char**) in Test.o
  "dlib::popup_menu_region::disable()", referenced from:
      void dlib::image_display::set_image<dlib::array2d<unsigned char, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > >(dlib::array2d<unsigned char, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > const&) in Test.o
      void dlib::image_display::set_image<dlib::matrix_op<dlib::op_heatmap<dlib::array2d<unsigned char, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > > > >(dlib::matrix_op<dlib::op_heatmap<dlib::array2d<unsigned char, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > > > const&) in Test.o
      void dlib::image_display::set_image<dlib::matrix_op<dlib::op_jet<dlib::array2d<unsigned char, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > > > >(dlib::matrix_op<dlib::op_jet<dlib::array2d<unsigned char, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > > > const&) in Test.o
      void dlib::image_display::set_image<dlib::array2d<dlib::rgb_pixel, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > >(dlib::array2d<dlib::rgb_pixel, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > const&) in Test.o
  "dlib::image_window::get_next_double_click(dlib::vector<long, 2l>&, unsigned long&)", referenced from:
      Test::test(int, char**) in Test.o
  "_USER_ERROR__missing_dlib_all_source_cpp_file__OR__inconsistent_use_of_DEBUG_or_ENABLE_ASSERTS_preprocessor_directives_", referenced from:
      __GLOBAL__sub_I_Test.cpp in Test.o
  "dlib::entropy_decoder_kernel_2::set_stream(std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&)", referenced from:
      void dlib::load_dng<dlib::array2d<dlib::rgb_pixel, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > >(dlib::array2d<dlib::rgb_pixel, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> >&, std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) in Test.o
  "dlib::image_display::~image_display()", referenced from:
      dlib::image_window::image_window<dlib::array2d<unsigned char, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > >(dlib::array2d<unsigned char, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in Test.o
      dlib::image_window::image_window<dlib::matrix_op<dlib::op_heatmap<dlib::array2d<unsigned char, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > > > >(dlib::matrix_op<dlib::op_heatmap<dlib::array2d<unsigned char, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > > > const&) in Test.o
      dlib::image_window::image_window<dlib::matrix_op<dlib::op_jet<dlib::array2d<unsigned char, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > > > >(dlib::matrix_op<dlib::op_jet<dlib::array2d<unsigned char, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > > > const&) in Test.o
      dlib::image_window::image_window<dlib::array2d<dlib::rgb_pixel, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > >(dlib::array2d<dlib::rgb_pixel, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in Test.o
  "dlib::image_window::~image_window()", referenced from:
      Test::test(int, char**) in Test.o
  "dlib::image_display::image_display(dlib::drawable_window&)", referenced from:
      dlib::image_window::image_window<dlib::array2d<unsigned char, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > >(dlib::array2d<unsigned char, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in Test.o
      dlib::image_window::image_window<dlib::matrix_op<dlib::op_heatmap<dlib::array2d<unsigned char, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > > > >(dlib::matrix_op<dlib::op_heatmap<dlib::array2d<unsigned char, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > > > const&) in Test.o
      dlib::image_window::image_window<dlib::matrix_op<dlib::op_jet<dlib::array2d<unsigned char, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > > > >(dlib::matrix_op<dlib::op_jet<dlib::array2d<unsigned char, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > > > const&) in Test.o
      dlib::image_window::image_window<dlib::array2d<dlib::rgb_pixel, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > >(dlib::array2d<dlib::rgb_pixel, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in Test.o
  "dlib::entropy_decoder_kernel_2::~entropy_decoder_kernel_2()", referenced from:
      void dlib::load_dng<dlib::array2d<dlib::rgb_pixel, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > >(dlib::array2d<dlib::rgb_pixel, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> >&, std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) in Test.o
  "Test::add(int, int)", referenced from:
      -[Wrapper add_wrapper:add:] in example.o
  "dlib::image_window::on_image_clicked(dlib::vector<long, 2l> const&, bool, unsigned long)", referenced from:
      dlib::image_window::image_window<dlib::array2d<unsigned char, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > >(dlib::array2d<unsigned char, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in Test.o
      dlib::image_window::image_window<dlib::matrix_op<dlib::op_heatmap<dlib::array2d<unsigned char, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > > > >(dlib::matrix_op<dlib::op_heatmap<dlib::array2d<unsigned char, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > > > const&) in Test.o
      dlib::image_window::image_window<dlib::matrix_op<dlib::op_jet<dlib::array2d<unsigned char, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > > > >(dlib::matrix_op<dlib::op_jet<dlib::array2d<unsigned char, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > > > const&) in Test.o
      dlib::image_window::image_window<dlib::array2d<dlib::rgb_pixel, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > >(dlib::array2d<dlib::rgb_pixel, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in Test.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

[image]

First of all, I have no idea how does Xcode's linker find exactly body in libdlib.a though I didn't put the full path of it

- library search path: $(PROJECT_DIR)/lib

I want to call the function from dlib in Testcpp source and wrap it using example source and finally invoke to swift code

What is wrong with it?

Env.

- Mac (OSX) Catalina 10.15.4
- SwiftUI (working with)
- XCode 11.4
- iPhone 6S
- IOS 13.4.1

Answer (score 0):

This error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture arm64

means that the library you're trying to integrate is built for an architecture different from arm64, the one you're trying to run on. You need to rebuild the C++ library to arm64 then integrate it.

Comment: I already tried it on laptop and it said "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64." 
That's why I didn't find the reason from the building target. As you know the same error can be appeared because header can't find its body. 
but I'm not sure I'm on right way. thank you for your comment anyway